# How to repair the front panel of this unusual kitchen drawer?

Tags: drawers

Our utensils drawer has two problems, one of which is that the front is poorly attached to the drawer box. (The other problem, not the focus of this question, is that one of the back wheels is gone and the other back wheel is wobbly). Unfortunately, I could find little information on this particular drawer mechanism (see images 2 and 3 below, they are animated). The drawer and mechanism are at least 30 years old. The drawer is 495 mm wide and 465 mm deep. The mechanism is not a "quiet drawer" mechanism.

As a temporary solution, someone in my family used silicone glue to keep the drawer from being unusable:

[image]

Without the silicone, the left side of the front panel detaches completely from the drawer box. With the silicone the drawer's front panel is still weakly attached to the drawer box and it wobbles. We had to move the utensils into another drawer. I would like a real solution so that we can move the utensils back into this drawer again.

Silicone glue is easy to remove when dry. I removed the glue on one side to reveal the mechanism of the drawer as well as the problem (the following two images are animated gifs):

[image]
[image]

The only thing on the drawer that I could find that might help identify the model or manufacturer is the following:

[image]

The whole drawer looks like this:

[image]

How can I repair the front of the drawer so that it becomes solidly attached to the drawer box again? (And what type of mechanism is this? It looks much more complicated than the drawer mechanisms I am reading about online. Again, it is not a quiet drawer mechanism.)

Comment: Have you tried turning any of the screws that are on the sides? On drawers like these, the screws adjust the front so it can be raised and moved side to side to get the gaps even between drawers and the fronts level. One of the screws may be the one that holds the drawer front in place. Slowly turn one screw to see what happens, it won't move a lot but it should be detectable.

Comment: Here is a tutorial that shows how to adjust a similar set up.    https://www.kzkitchen.com/post/european-cabinet-hinge-and-drawer-adjustment-guide